# How to pass and run a callback method in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, notifications

I have a Manager (main thread), that creates other Threads to handle various operations.
I would like my Manager to be notified when a Thread it created ends (when run() method execution is finished).

I know I could do it by checking the status of all my threads with the Thread.isActive() method, but polling sucks, so I wanted to have notifications.

I was thinking of giving a callback method to the Threads, and call this function at the end of the run() method:

```
class Manager():
    ...
    MyThread(self.on_thread_finished).start() # How do I pass the callback

    def on_thread_finished(self, data):
        pass
    ...

class MyThread(Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ....
        self.callback(data) # How do I call the callback?
    ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am interested in a non-threaded callback method example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The thread can't call the manager unless it has a reference to the manager.  The easiest way for that to happen is for the manager to give it to the thread at instantiation.

```
class Manager(object):
    def new_thread(self):
        return MyThread(parent=self)
    def on_thread_finished(self, thread, data):
        print thread, data

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        # ...
        self.parent and self.parent.on_thread_finished(self, 42)

mgr    = Manager()
thread = mgr.new_thread()
thread.start()
```

If you want to be able to assign an arbitrary function or method as a callback, rather than storing a reference to the manager object, this becomes a bit problematic because of method wrappers and such. It's hard to design the callback so it gets a reference to both the manager *and* the thread, which is what you will want. I worked on that for a while and did not come up with anything I'd consider useful or elegant.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `thread.start()`? Otherwise, no actual multithreading will occur and `MyThread.run()` gets executed like any other function. But if you actually run `MyThread.start()` and create a new thread, `self.parent.on_thread_finished(self, 42)` will still be executed in the new thread's context instead of the main thread. You will need some kind of synchronization, like a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), so @jonathan-lillesæter is actually correct.

Comment: New to Python. Isn't this a misuse of inheritance? `MyThread` doesn't seem like a logical child of `Manager`.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that using this solution will execute the callback function inside the secondary thread, not the main thread.
Also, what is the use of evaluating `self.parent` in function `run` ? Is this to prevent `self.parent.on_thread_finished` from being called if `parent` is `None` ? Why would you do that instead of using an `if` statement ? This is confusing...

Answer (score 10):

Anything wrong with doing it this way?

```
from threading import Thread

class Manager():
    def Test(self):
        MyThread(self.on_thread_finished).start()

    def on_thread_finished(self, data):
        print "on_thread_finished:", data

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = callback

    def run(self):
        data = "hello"
        self.callback(data)

m = Manager()
m.Test() # prints "on_thread_finished: hello"
```

Comment: You cannot pass the local method on_thread_finished to the thread as callback because the local method takes two arguments. When the callback is called from the thread, it will give only one argument (data)

Comment: I know this is late, but for anyone else who is about to spend an hour rewriting a large chunk of code: Bharathwaaj's comment is *completely incorrect* and this answer works perfectly.

Comment: @Shariq, the problem is that `on_thread_finished` still runs in the child thread, not in the `Manager`. You can't make `Manager` do it because `Manager` is *doing something else* at this time. To see the problem, just make `Test()` hang in a dead loop after calling `MyThread()`. Alternatively, define a local variable and try using it within `on_thread_finished()`, e.g. `number_of_threads_running -=1`

Comment: This won't work if the manager is in a tkinter GUI, you can't call the GUI's functions from a work thread

Answer (score 4):

If you want the main thread to wait for children threads to finish execution, you are probably better off using some kind of synchronization mechanism. If simply being notified when one or more threads has finished executing, a [Condition](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) is enough:

```
import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, condition):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.condition = condition

    def run(self):
        print "%s done" % threading.current_thread()
        with self.condition:
            self.condition.notify()


condition = threading.Condition()
condition.acquire()

thread = MyThread(condition)
thread.start()

condition.wait()
```

However, using a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) is probably better, as it makes handling multiple worker threads a bit easier.